# Microsoft Visual Studio is Busy when trying to clean the solution using Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017, busy-waiting, visual-studio-project

I have an application created by Xamarin.Forms (PCL)

When I try to Clean the solution,

visual-studio goes to stops working,
and I can't open any file or press anything to close it.

just by killing the visual-studio process
'End Process Tree for visual studio.exe'.

if I try to **build** or **rebuild** the solution **is done** without any problems.

if I try to **clean** Xamarin.Android or Web-Application solution is **done**.

the problem appears just in Xamarin.Forms solutions.

**how I can solve this problem?**

[image]

Comment: If you plan to use "Enable UI Debugging for XAML", make sure your current solution is not set to Lightweight Solution Load: In the options->Project and Solution, make sure that "Lightweight Solution Load" is disabled. Also make sure that in the solution properties, "Lightweight load" is not turn on .

If you don't plan to use "Enable UI Debugging for XAML", uncheck Debug -> Options -> Enable UI debugging for XAML.

Comment: What is your VS version? Did  you test it in the latest version of VS(15.8.7)?

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT I've tried your solution,
but Visual Studio still stops working

Comment: @YorkShen-MSFT I'm using visual studio 2017 (15.8.0)  and I didn't test it on the latest version.


should I have the latest version to get rid of this problem?

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT I wonder!? What is the command which visual-studio carries out until he stops working?

Comment: Try to update your VS .This problem did appeared in some old version.But have solved in the newest version.If it still doesn't work,you can add a issue in VS   Help -> Send feedback --> report a problem

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT I will try it, thank you very much :)

Comment: Tell me the result whether it works or not

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT Thank you for your help, your suggestion has successful after I tried to rebuild the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many attempts, I found the solution without installing the latest version of the visual studio.

**Step 1:** Disable lightweight solution load

Tools → Option → Projects and Solutions →  Lightweight solution load

[image]

**Step 2:** Make sure in the solution properties **Lightweight Solution load** is disable

[image]

**Step 3:** Uncheck **Enable UI Debugging Tools for XAML**

Tools → Option → Debugging → General → Enable UI Debugging Tools for XAML

[image]

**Step 4:** **Rebuild** Solution  → **Clean** Solution

Also, you can clean the solution from **Build** → **BatchBuild**

[image]

**References**

- [Lightweight Solution Load in Visual Studio 2017](https://dotnetvibes.com/2017/02/13/lightweight-solution-load-in-visual-studio-2017/)
- [UI Debugging Tools for XAML" enabled causes program to hang for long periods](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/168948/debugging-with-ui-debugging-tools-for-xaml-enabled.html)

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the .vs folder manually and relaunching the Visual Studio again solved my problem.